# Should I Create Functions Inside The Component or Put Them In The State (Zustand)

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management, zustand

Hope you're doing fine!

Here's my question. Where should I store functions? In a Component, or directly in the store?

Suppose I have a component called RevisionList. One RevisionList renders multiple revisions (**Revision** component). You can select each revision by clicking on it. So each revision needs to make use of the method called setCurRev.

So, I have two options here.
Either define it inside the **Revision** component:

```
  const curRevId = useStore(s => s.curRevId);
  const hideRefRevFinalVer = useStore(s => s.hideRefRevFinalVer)
  const app = useStore(s => s.app);

  const setCurRev = (id: RevId) => {
    if (id === curRevId) return;
    hideRefRevFinalVer();
    app.setRevisionById(id);
  };
```

Or I could define it directly in the state slice:

```
const setCurRev = (id: RevId) => {
    if (id === get().curRev?.id) return;

    get().hideRefRevFinalVer();
    get().app.setRevisionById(id);
  };
```

And then use it in the Revision component like this:

```
const setCurRev = useStore(s => s.setCurRev)
```

Which is a better option in your opinion? I guess the second variant may cause fewer rerenders, so I should go with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, set and get functions should be defined in the state slice. This way you can reuse them in many components.

Here is an example from Zustand's Github repo:

```
import omit from "lodash-es/omit"

const useStore = create(set => ({
  salmon: 1,
  tuna: 2,
  deleteEverything: () => set({ }, true), // clears the entire store, actions included
  deleteTuna: () => set(state => omit(state, ['tuna']), true)
}))
```

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense! Thanks for your input.